# Vmware host: accessing a forwarded port from a virtual host

Tags: localhost, vmware-workstation

A windows host machine (which dynamically has the address 192.168.227.1) runs

- (i) an ssh tunnel with port forwarding (forwards the port localhost:5432 with the following command: `autossh.exe -M 2000 -L 5432:localhost:5432 server`
- (ii) vmware linux machine (ubuntu)

How can I access the 5432 port of the host machine from linux? The port forwarding binds 5432 port with the localhost (127.0.0.1) and not with the dynamically assigned ip address (192.168.227.1). This makes it impossible to access the port with 192.168.227.1:5432

Unfortunatelly I cannot do the port forwarding directly from the linux VM.

Comments?

Answer (score 0):

=) This are some easy easy points... If you look closer to your port forward **-L** you are using [nothing]:5432:localhost:5432 just replace nothing with the ip address that you want to have the port listening or, just add 0.0.0.0:5432:localhost:5432 server and you will have in all interfaces that port listening.